# node.js forever-monitor does not use child directory on linux

Tags: node.js, forever

I am trying to run a node script that launches other scripts in a child directory ./host using forever-monitor.

On windows this works

```
var child = new (forever.Monitor)('host.js', {
  max: 1,
  silent: false,
  options: [],
  cwd:"./host"
});
```

On linux I get

```
/home/ec2-user/test/node_modules/forever-monitor/node_modules/broadway/node_modules/eventemitter2/lib/eventemitter2.js:283
          throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                         ^
Error: Target script does not exist: host.js
    at /home/ec2-user/test/node_modules/forever-monitor/lib/forever-monitor/monitor.js:144:26
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

If I change the first line to `var child = new (forever.Monitor)('./host/host.js', {` I now get

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/ec2-user/test/host/host/host.js'
```

if I use `child = new (forever.Monitor)('/home/ec2-user/test/host/host.js', {` it runs, but I would rather not hard code the directory.

I'm using:
  forever-monitor 1.2.3

How do I get this to work on linux?

**Edit** - adding examples of the above problem with changes to the names of the directories and script, maybe the `/host/host.js` is causing some confusion.  Using `/childDir/script.js` instead.

The parent script is running as `/home/ec2-user/test/parentScript.js`

It calls the child script `/home/ec2-user/test/childDir/script.js` using forever-monitor.

The first example at the top works perfectly in Windows but on Linux it is ignoring the cwd option and throws `Error: Target script does not exist: script.js`

If I add the directory to the script call (Same thing happens using sourceDir.)

```
var child = new (forever.Monitor)('./childDir/script.js', {
```

cwd is now added to the call making it skip the directory the script is in and not finding the script.

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/ec2-user/test/childDir/childDir/script.js'
```

So the possibilities I see are.

1. There is a bug when running on linux that makes cwd only fire if
   forever-monitor detects a directory change.
2. There is a bug when running on both linux and windows where cwd is not intended to modify the path to the script being called, but on windows #1 is not happening and it always adds to the script path.
3. I completely mis-understanding how this is supposed to work.

I assume one of these options should work on both windows and Linux.  What is the correct way to do this?

```
var child = new (forever.Monitor)('script.js', {
  max: 1,
  silent: false,
  options: [],
  cwd:"./childDir"
});
```

or (assuming cwd is not supposed to modify the script source directory)

```
var child = new (forever.Monitor)('script.js', {
  max: 1,
  silent: false,
  options: [],
  sourceDir:"./childDir",
  cwd:"./childDir"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `sourceDir` option instead of the `cwd` option and you should get the results you are trying to achieve. The `cwd` is used for the eventual call to `child_process.spawn` while the `sourceDir` is used for looking up where the child script is located. Keep in mind that you will want to use a combination of `__dirname` and `path.resolve()` to normalize the path.

## Edit:

You run your script like so:

```
/home/user$ node startup.js
```

Which sets the `cwd` for the node process running `startup.js` as `/home/user`. So if you run the command above with `host.js` in that directory with a `startup.js` file looking like below:

```
// startup.js
var child = new (forever.Monitor)('host.js', { 
  max: 1,
  silent: false,
  options: []
});
```

it has a `cwd` of `/home/user` and since `host.js` is in that directory, all is good.

If you start it like

```
/home/user/some/other/path$ node /home/user/startup.js
```

Then your `cwd` for the `startup.js` script is /home/user/some/other/path and therefore can't find `host.js` in its cwd. So in this instance we have to define the `sourceDir` to the location of `host.js` as `/home/user`

Comment: I'm guessing the way cwd is 'working' on Linux is probably a bug, but your answer solved my problem and I like the __dirname solution better than using cwd.  Thanks.

Comment: Not a bug when you think about what it is doing. You are asking `forever` to lookup a script and run, thats what the `sourceDir` is for. The `cwd` option is for the forked child process resulting from running the script in `sourceDir`. Sure, they could concat this into one option, but then the tool looses flexibility (i.e. lazy loading a directory of start scripts that each do work in other areas on the system)

Comment: Yes, I want the forked child process to run in a different directory.  I'm not asking it to look up a script and run it, I'm asking it to start another application in another directory.  That's why I used the Child Working Directory setting.  The problem is, it doesn't work properly on the linux server I'm using.  It works fine in windows.  Look at the different cases I listed above and you'll see what I mean.  If it's not a bug, then how do you get it to work?

Comment: Guaranteed this isn't a bug. Nodejitsu uses `forever` as their process manager in their production stack and their entire PaaS is run on linux boxes. I will try and update my answer to explain further, but the answer to this lies in the source of `forever`. I would suggest poking around there to learn.

Comment: Your workaround gets me past the bug, but you are mis-understanding the problem.  I will update the question.

Comment: You're still misunderstanding the way the script works. I would suggest digging into the code and following the logic line. It becomes quite clear when you do so. And if you still feel strongly about it being a bug, then you should open an issue https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever-monitor/issues

Comment: Oh, also, the nodejitsu guys are quite active on IRC (#nodejitsu), they might be able to give you better guidance with your setup and how things work under the covers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42884/discussion-between-diver-and-jibsales)